# How to summon a different animal using Kuchiyose?

Tags: naruto

As we know, every ninja needs to sign a contract to summon an animal. However, Sasuke suddenly summoned a hawk, after summoning snakes all the time.

How can someone change the animal he summons?

> I know that with *Keiyaku Fūin*, the contract can be broken, but I guess that works a little bit different, not?

Comment: I guess that Sasuke must've signed a new contract that we have not seen. As far as I know you cannot summon without previously signing a contract.

Comment: @JNat: That's true - But I got the impression, that a contract cannot be broken?

Comment: @looper: but maybe he did not break the other contract. He may just not summon snakes anymore. I guess.

Comment: @looper: There's no reason to believe that contracts are exclusive; someone could get their hands on contract scrolls for turtle, snake & snail and have his own reptile army (chakra permitting)

Comment: @Alok: Then why people only have one contract? These contracts are not super-secret, or are they?

Comment: curious what makes you think they have one contract? Pain summoned all sorts of crazy animals.

Comment: @Morpheus: There are multiple reasons: 1.) Naruto didn't know how to determine the animal that should appear - It seems that it was determined by his blood. 2.) Same with Orochimaru. When he wasn't able to use his hands, Kabuto used his blood to summon, without having the contract - It seems that... You know ;). Regarding Pain: He used the Animal Path, which needs neither signs, nor blood - Plus, the summoned creatures have the rinnegan, I doubt that it's normal Kuchiyose.

Comment: @looper: In the latest chapter (633) Sasuke summons a snake, which means that (as I had said above) he did not break the contract he had with snakes, he just 'signed' a new contract with hawks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kuchiyose is a highly controversial jutsu, cloaked in mystery.

At the beginning of the series, Naruto is presented with the frog contract scroll. In which he signs with blood, thereby validating the contract. From that point onward, he can summon frogs. The same happens with Jiraiya (who's name is earlier on the list).

Orochimaru has a tattoo on his right arm, on which he smears the blood required for the summon.

Madara Uchiha was seen summoning the Kyuubi after taking control of it, and using it in battle against Hashirama, seemingly without a contract.

Tobi was seen using the same technique after he unsealed him from Kushina.

As for the Rinnegan's Animal Path, it's very likely to assume that the summoned animals are some sort of zombies as well (much like the Rikudo no Jutsu's bodies), as they have the Rinnegan and the Piercing (and doesn't talk at all).

---

It seems that a general contract with the species, or control over the specific creature is enough. If there's a contract, both sides can freely summon each other (As seen by Shima's reverse summoning). If there isn't one, it probably takes the "consent" of both sides for the technique to work (Or, the forced consent, in the case of the Kyuubi).

---

The technique is very unclear in nature. It's a space-time ninjutsu, which on itself is a mystery, and very little is known about it. We don't have much more detail than that.

Comment: I think the part of your answer mentioning Madare Uchiha should be in a spoiler block because it has a lot of information that is spoiler-y.

Comment: @kuwaly: Not at all. It's a known fact that Madara *had* used the Kyuubi against Hashirama.

Comment: Okay. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the contracts are exclusive, but to answer in terms of Pain, Madara, & Obito, The [*Animal Path*](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Animal_Path) requires no blood or hand symbols, thus it's safe to assume standard rules like a contract doesn't apply, Madara & Obito could summon the 10 tails because they had the Rinnegan & its accompanying chakra & could use the Animal Path of the [*Six Paths*](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Six_Paths_of_Pain) abilities.

Pain could summon whatever he wanted & apply his own jutsu to whatever he summoned as seen with the [*Giant Multi-Headed Dog*](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Giant_Multi-Headed_Dog) that he summoned, the only difference with those summons & the 10 tails was that they had been modified using the chakra conducting rods (receptor rods) & were the equivalent of zombies with no control of their own bodies & no evident consciousness as the rods allows Pain to control the beast entirely by channeling his chakra through the rods, this gave them Rinnegan as the chakra flowing through them (From Nagato) was Six Paths chakra. Something could be dead & with chakra rods you could make it seem as they are alive (queue the 6 paths of Pain).

Naruto never bothered/tried to try sign a contract with any other species so only summoned frogs but he could have also signed a contract with a bear or that crazy Pterodactyl race Pain found etc.